# Three.js: children can't use lookAt independently of parent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm learning `Three.js` and I'm trying to have an object to rotate according to the mouse movement.
The object is a face built in Blender and has two children objects representing the eyes. Ideally, face and eyes should rotate in the direction of the mouse independent of each other.

In order to this, I'm using an invisible plane to `raycast` the mouse position and then have the object to "look" towards the mouse cursor using the `lookAt()` function. If I keep the face still, and try to move the eyes only, it works fine. The moment I do the same for the face, the face rotates, but the eyes don't anymore.

This is object being loaded:

```
var object;
loader.load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/312969/faccione_test.glb", function(gltf) {
  object = gltf.scene;
  var scale = 20;
  gltf.scene.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
  gltf.scene.position.x = 50; //Position (x = right+ left-)
  gltf.scene.position.y = 0; //Position (y = up+, down-)
  gltf.scene.position.z = 0; //Position (z = front +, back-)

  scene.add(object);

  gltf.scene.name = "faccione";
  render();
  animate();
});
```

And in the render function I use the lookAt():

```
function render() {
  object.children[0].lookAt(point);
  object.children[1].lookAt(point);

  // uncommenting this blocks the eyes rotation
  // object.lookAt(point);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Reading a bit around I understood that loading the eyes separately and then adding them to the scene should make it possible to move them independently. I wanted to understand, though, if there was a way to achieve the same result loading the whole object at once.

Here's a codepen of the whole thing: https://codepen.io/qarlo/pen/9ed6626a793227cc3a2d8ef122927686

Comment: What is the expected result? If they're all looking at the same point they wont really rotate independently (you might get a bit of cross-eye but thats all)

Comment: I was expecting (probably wrongly) that the eyes, having a different center respect to the face, would also rotate differently. They probably do, but very slightly so it's not really noticeable. I asked the same in another forum and the thread might be helpful: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-use-lookat-for-children-and-parent-objects-at-the-same-time/5725/4
I'm opting to limit the head movement and let the eyes move freely